# Why is data input "O-11" less than data input "O-6" in coding?

Tags: php, sql

I'm currently coding a Unit Management System in PHP. I have the following code:

```
<?php
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM ranks WHERE grade_level <= "O-6" ORDER BY id ASC");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['rank_name']."</option>";
      }
?>
```

I want it to only show ranks below/including Colonel (O-6), but it shows ranks General (O-10) and General of the Army (O-11) as well. I can't figure out why that second digit isn't registered thus making it worth more than the single digit.

My question is also seemingly too broad for Google's search algorithm.

Comment: You are comparing a string and not an integer. If you have a look into the ASCII table you will see that the "1" is before the "6". Therefore "O-11" is less than "O-6" since each character gets compared to the other one by one.

Comment: which db you are using ??'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) function to extract the numeric part of the `grade_level` column (to the right of the `-`) and test on that:

```
SELECT * FROM ranks WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(grade_level, '-', -1) <= 6
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4cfeee303a39860341e3daaf6a6b5005)

Comment: This worked perfectly! I only had to change it from '-' to 'O-' to account for the Enlisted ranks (E-).

Comment: @ConnorLx3 I would probably add `SUBSTRING_INDEX(grade_level, '-', 1) = 'O'` as a safer way of excluding the enlisted ranks.

Comment: Well, I don't want to exclude the enlisted ranks entirely, I just didn't want them to be affected by the substring so that E-7 through E-9 will still show.

Comment: @ConnorLx3 that sounds like you might actually want a double barrelled `where` e,g, `SUBSTRING_INDEX(grade_level, '-', 1) = 'O' AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(grade_level, '-', -1) <= 6 OR SUBSTRING_INDEX(grade_level, '-', 1) = 'E'`

Answer (score 0):

if you want compare the integer value at the right of the string and the string is always prefixed  by the 2 char `O-`

Assuming you are using Sql-Server

```
SELECT * FROM ranks 
WHERE cast(right(grade_level, len(grade_level) -2) AS INT)  <=  
  cast(right("O-6", len("O-6") -2) as INT)  
ORDER BY id ASC
```